# WAT vs IIS Manager to manage configuration in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis, configuration

When creating asp.net (mvc 3) applications do I need to use IIS Manager to set roles, membership and profiles or I can do all this things in embedded in Visual Studio Web Site Administration Tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage roles, membership and profiles on IIS you will need to develop admin pages, so for the start the best way would be to use Site Administration Tool inside VS environment.

Comment: Sir, why should I develop admin pages? As I understand in developing process I can use Site Administration Tool, but when the app is deployed I should use IIS Manager? Thanks in advance

Comment: Site Administration Tool inside VS is not part of published files, you can't use them on IIS.